# SQL Syntax Error - When starting civicrm with joomla

Tags: joomla, mysql, php, civicrm-home, sql

Please help, i have no idea what is wrong, all is fine until i open civicrm with joomla, it displays sql syntax error, then when I try to look at my db functions with phpmyadmin there will be a whole page of error, i will be kicked out and unable to login until i restart my computer
-joomla 3.8.7
-apache 24
-php 7.2.4
-mysql 8.0.11.0
-civicrm 5.0.1
-phpmyadmin 4.8.0.1

```
Apr 24 03:27:15  [info] $Fatal Error Details = Array
(
[callback] => Array
    (
        [0] => CRM_Core_Error
        [1] => handle
    )

[code] => -2
[message] => DB Error: syntax error
[mode] => 16
[debug_info] => 
SELECT  v.label as label ,v.name as value, v.grouping as grouping
FROM   civicrm_option_value v,
   civicrm_option_group g
WHERE  v.option_group_id = g.id
AND  g.name            = 'languages'
AND  g.is_active       = 1  AND  v.is_active = 1  AND ( v.component_id IS NULL  OR v.component_id IN (SELECT id FROM civicrm_component WHERE name IN ("CiviEvent","CiviContribute","CiviMember","CiviMail","CiviReport","CiviPledge")) )  ORDER BY v.weight [nativecode=1064 ** You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'grouping
FROM   civicrm_option_value v,
   civicrm_option_group g
WHERE  v.o' at line 1]
[type] => DB_Error
[user_info] => 
SELECT  v.label as label ,v.name as value, v.grouping as grouping
FROM   civicrm_option_value v,
   civicrm_option_group g
WHERE  v.option_group_id = g.id
AND  g.name            = 'languages'
AND  g.is_active       = 1  AND  v.is_active = 1  AND ( v.component_id IS NULL  OR v.component_id IN (SELECT id FROM civicrm_component WHERE name IN ("CiviEvent","CiviContribute","CiviMember","CiviMail","CiviReport","CiviPledge")) )  ORDER BY v.weight [nativecode=1064 ** You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'grouping
FROM   civicrm_option_value v,
   civicrm_option_group g
WHERE  v.o' at line 1]
[to_string] => [db_error: message="DB Error: syntax error" code=-2 mode=callback callback=CRM_Core_Error::handle prefix="" info="
SELECT  v.label as label ,v.name as value, v.grouping as grouping
FROM   civicrm_option_value v,
   civicrm_option_group g
WHERE  v.option_group_id = g.id
AND  g.name            = 'languages'
AND  g.is_active       = 1  AND  v.is_active = 1  AND ( v.component_id IS NULL  OR v.component_id IN (SELECT id FROM civicrm_component WHERE name IN ("CiviEvent","CiviContribute","CiviMember","CiviMail","CiviReport","CiviPledge")) )  ORDER BY v.weight [nativecode=1064 ** You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'grouping
FROM   civicrm_option_value v,
   civicrm_option_group g
WHERE  v.o' at line 1]"]
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it seems php 7.2 is not compatible with 5.x.x
or i do not know how to do the configuration

i think downgrade the php would be the best solution
but i wonder if there is other answer, and how to do it....

[image]



updates: 
-downgrade php does not help, same error appears
**-downgrade mysql to 5.5 works!**